# Phonegap - my app runs perfectly on device browser, but not in App - Android

Tags: android, cordova

I am experiencing an interesting bug which Im unable to figure out... I have a phonegap app that run perfectly on iOS however on Android it is a different story.

The app is running well on some android devices however on a few the HTC 1 in particular all the elements of the page are laid out very odd... I have tried targeting more media queries etc however when I uploaded the app to a server and ran it on the HTC 1 and it runs perfectly... Which leads me to believe the problem is infact the Cordova settings...

Are there device specific settings to Android on Phonegap that make it act differently than the native android browser?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you link to some stylesheets that are on remote servers in your app. And the (native) app is restricted to load it, because the origin is not set correctly.

Try to alter

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
```

to

```
<access origin="*" />
```

in your config.xml and try again.

lg fastrde

Comment: Thanks fastrde, the origin is set to * in my config.xml. I am running phonegap 3.1.0. This problem only seems to be occurring on certain devices though. Could it be something to do with jquery or any JavaScript? Or is it likely to be a CSS issue? Thanks again. T